# Почему определение метода как свойства функции объекта-прототипа вызывает ошибку?

Tags: javascript

Продолжаю читать *"JavaScript. Подробное руководство"* Флэнагана. В примере 9.3 (complex.js) встретил неочевидную для меня вещь.

Методы экземпляров класса определяются как свойства функции объекта-прототипа:

```
Complex.prototype.add = function(that) {};
Complex.prototype.mul = function(that) {};
Complex.prototype.mag = function() {};
Complex.prototype.neg = function() {};
Complex.prototype.toString = function() {};
Complex.prototype.equals = function(that) {};
```

В том же примере метод *parse()* определяется так:

```
Complex.parse = function(s) {};
```

а не так:

```
Complex.prototype.parse = function(s) {};
```

Более того, почему попытка определить метод как свойство функции объекта-прототипа вызывает ошибку?

Код из книги:

```
// Класс комплекстных чисел. Определяется класс Complex, представляющий
// комплексные числа.

// Функция-констуктор определяет поля экземпляра r и i в каждом создаваемом 
// экземпляре. Эти поля хранят значения вещественной и мнимой частей
// комплексного числа: они хранят информацию, уникальную для каждого
// объекта.
function Complex(real, imaginary) {
    if( isNaN(real) || isNaN(imaginary) )   // Убедиться, что аргументы - числа
        throw new TypeError();              // Иначе возбудить исключение
    this.r = real;                          // Вещественная часть числа
    this.i = imaginary;                     // Мнимая часть числа
}

//
// Методы экземпляров класса определяются как свойства-функции объекта-прототипа.
// Методы, определяемые ниже, наследуются всеми экземплярами и обеспечивают
// общность поведения класса. Обратите внимание, что методы экземпляров в JavaScript 
// должны использовать ключевое слово this для доступа к полям экземпляра.
Complex.prototype.add = function(that) {
    return new Complex(this.r + that.r, this.i + that.i);
};

// Умножает текущее комплексное число на число that и возвращает произведение.
Complex.prototype.mul = function(that) {
    return new Complex(this.r * that.r - this.i * that.i,
                       this.r * that.i + this.i * that.r);
};

// Возвращает вещественный модуль комплексного числа. Он определяется
// как растояние до числа на комплексной плоскости от точки (0,0).
Complex.prototype.mag = function() {
    return Math.sqrt(this.r * this.r + this.i * this.i);
};

// Возвращает комплексное число с противоположным знаком.
Complex.prototype.neg = function() {
    return new Complex(-this.r, -this.i);
};

// Преобразует объект Complex в строку в понятном формате
Complex.prototype.toString = function() {
    return '{' + this.r + ',' + this.i + '}';
};

//Проверяет равенство данного комплексного числа с заданным
Complex.prototype.equals = function(that) {
    return that != null && // Должно быть определено, не равно null
           that.constructor === Complex && // и быть экземпляром Complex
           this.r === that.r && // и иметь те же значения.
           this.i === that.i;
};

// Ниже определяется несколько полей класса, хранящих предопределенные
// комплексные числа. Их имена состоят исключительно из заглавных символов,
// чтобы показать, что они являются константами.
// (В ECMA5Script 5 эти свойства можно было бы сделать доступными только для чтения)
Complex.ZERO = new Complex(0,0);
Complex.ONE  = new Complex(1,0);
Complex.I    = new Complex(0,1);

// Следующий метод анализирует строку в формате, возвращаемом методом
// экземпляра toSrting, и возвращает объект Complex или возбуждает исключение TypeError&
Complex.parse = function(s) {
    try { // Предполагается, что анализ пройдет успешно
        var m = Complex._format.exec(s); // Регулярное выражение
        return new Complex(parseFloat(m[1]), parseFloat(m[2]));
    } catch (x) { // Возбудить исключение в случае неудачи
        throw new TypeError("Строка '" + s + "' не может быть преобразована" +
                            " в комплексное число.");
    }
};

// "Частное" поле класса, используемое методом Complex.parse().
// Символ подчеркивания в его имени указывает, что оно предназначение
// для внутреннего использования и не является частью общедоступного API класса.
Complex._format = /^\{([^,]+),([^}]+)\}$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, `Complex.parse` - аналог `static` метода класса. При создании объекта `Complex` в него копируются методы прототипа, но не функции-конструктора.

Сравниваем:

```
var b = new Complex(1, 0),
    c = new Complex(0, 1);
// public function mul ( that ), возвращает this * that
var d = d.mul(c);
// public static function parse( s ), 
// this не используется и возвращает конструктор
var e = Complex.parse('0,1');
```

И да, от написания `"Complex.prototype.parse = function(s) { ... }"` ошибки не произойдет, но 1) смысла в этом мало, 2) вызывать ее вне объекта надо будет через прототип:

```
var a = Complex.prototype.parse('0,1'); // return new Complex()
```

Answer (score 1):

Замечательная статья по этой теме -
http://habrahabr.ru/post/140810/